# Progressive enhancement for javascript?

Tags: javascript, progressive-enhancement

Most people talk about progressive enhancement right now as serving browsers with javascript (enhanced version), and browsers without javascript (simple version).

But there is such a big difference in javascript performance between browsers that it may be useful to apply that term to support for choosing between javascript based features between browsers.

In a complex web app with numerous non-absolutely essential features (and animations), is it worthwhile to start thinking about cordoning them off for say, these sets of features should work in all browsers, and these sets of features only in Chrome and Safari, and these in Firefox and Chrome and Safari and Opera, and so on, because enabling certain features in certain browsers would be too slow.

Sometimes I feel like the user experience would improve if they did not have access to certain non-essential features. For instance disallowing IE users from resizing certain panels that Chrome users would be able to resize.

Comment: How do you handle it crescentfresh?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That sounds like a maintenance nightmare.

I realize that there are some web applications where it just doesn't make sense to have an html version. That said, if it's possible I would start by building an html version of every page first, then use JavaScript to *enhance* the user experience.

IE is less performant than Safari, Chrome and FF when it comes to JS - but have you really developed a page that is unusable in IE with JS turned on? I just haven't seen it - in the wild I think the various JS implementations are fast enough.

Comment: It's not unusable with JS turned on, it's just slower (the tradeoff value between added functionality/usability/prettiness and speed, is low) if I enable everything that I can in Chrome with no noticeable penalty.

Comment: Though you're totally right about it being a maintenance nightmare, hence the question, which is really to seek out if people have workable design patterns for this sort of thing.

Comment: There's also the gmail route. You could provide a "basic HTML" version.

Answer (score 1):

I have not done this myself, but i can see that it makes a lot of sense if your budget allows for it (and you can't control your user's browser choice)

At the end of the day, IE users may be using a slow browser, but they are still your users.  So if you want to give all your users the best possible user experience, it may be worth it to spend some time giving IE users a different version of the application to give them a higher level of performance.

An application that is fast for 99% of your users is undoubtably better than an application that is fast for only 30% of your users.  The only question is what's more important - the user experience, or your development time (and take into account that in a few years, the average user will be running faster browsers on faster computers)

Any such work should be driven by benchmarks though, since my experience is that you will often be surprised by what part of the code is slow and what part of the code is fast.

As an aside, [Lombardi Blueprint](http://googlecode.blogspot.com/2009/04/lombardi-blueprint-client-side-code.html) has a very interesting approach, although likely impractical outside of GWT.  They have layout algorithms written in java, written such that they can be run both on the client side (via GWT) and the server side (via a standard jvm).  Consequently, based on the benchmarked performance of your browser, they are able to dynamically switch between doing the layout on the client side (for fast browsers) vs doing the layout on the server side (for slower browsers).

Answer (score 0):

Two different issues with the browsers these days:

1. Speed. My experience has been that IE 7 works fine, just much slower than the rest. My fix is to give more frequent UI progress updates to the users. Since the UI updating takes time, I minimize the updates on the faster browsers. Eg on IE I update the screen with more feedback after processing another 50 events. For other browsers, after processing 200 events.
2. Lack of feature. Eg canvas. But it is big expense to build multiple sites. And test them too. So I spend my budget on 1 version for all current desktop browsers. And make additional sites for mobile esp iPhone.

HTH,

Larry

Answer (score 0):

What I do is to write a basic javascript file that has the common functionality, going to the lowest denominator (javascript 1.5).  I then have other files for more recent versions of javascript, and those will replace functions in my javascript objects, so that I can progressively add more support.

If I want to use the canvas tag, then I can add that in a different file, since IE and Firefox/Opera/Safari differ in how they create the canvas element.

This is not a joy on maintenance, but if I want to use the new html/javascript features then this seemed to be the best model.

Answer (score 0):

I concur with Andy. Providing different version of an application to different browsers is a potential maintenance problem down the road. I have always found it a better bet to provide one version of an app, that works in all browsers. For example, I try to avoid browser sniffers. The application might not be the coolest one, but it works for everyone and is easier to maintain.

This sort of stuff is easier now with all the nifty Javascript libraries that abstract some of the browser differences away. Besides, you can do a lot of stuff in the older browsers. It's just done "differently" ;)

Answer (score 0):

So let's say that you build a decently-sized application. You have browser-sniffing galore to determine what features will be on and which will be off. You sniffed for Opera 9.x, and now (today actually) Opera 10 comes out. You have to go and update every sniffer on every page. And then another browser comes out soon... and another. You are going to spend all your time, determining what browsers you support and what features to support on them.

I use multiple browsers in a day. So when I go to your site, I am going to see three different interfaces. I will be confused, since the features I expected to be there, or the behaviors I expected will not be there. Eventually, I'll get frustrated and never go to your site again.

Also, there is more to how quickly some piece of JavaScript runs than just the browser. I still have an old Pentium running Firefox 3.5. Sometimes, it can be painfully slow.

Comment: Well I agree that if it's as clumsy as you stated then it's not worth doing. But when Opera 11 comes out (with Carakan!), then I should be able to move or delete one line and move Opera from the limited feature set to the enhanced set.

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer is that you need to categorize your code into speed categories, not just categorize into browser capabilities.

In other words, give your site tiers of features, first tier is basic html, second tier is javascript usability improvements, third tier is javascript animation eye candy.

Then do a combination of allowing your users to step down a tier whenever they want to,  "Click to turn off animations!", "Click to turn on animations!", "Click to view in basic html", and choosing to default to certain speed categories based on browser for speed reasons (e.g. if IE7 seems to evince speed issues with the full animations on, make it default to the second "javascript usability improvements" tier).